# fitting loess in R with one inflection point only

Tags: r, smoothing, loess

Is there a way to fit loess to data with the constraint that it can only have one inflection point? If not how can I approximate it? I understand that I could use a larger span with loess, but that is not what I am looking for.

```
df <- structure(list(testage = c(0, 11, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 
            23, 24, 25, 27, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 
            42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
            58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 71), val = c(-6, 
            -0.72, 0.415, 0.479, 0.36, 0.556, 0.682, 0.695, 0.631, 0.685, 
            0.662, 0.538, 0.33, 0.64, 0.755, 0.48, 0.554, 0.675, 0.56, 0.545, 
            0.631, 0.611, 0.45, 0.395, 0.532, 0.536, 0.37, 0.552, 0.429, 
            0.45, 0.331, 0.316, 0.47, 0.144, -0.044, 0.065, 0.17, 0.29, 0.111, 
            -0.007, -0.018, -0.048, -0.187, -0.292, -0.273, -0.175, -0.476, 
            -0.145, -0.603, -0.279, -0.528, -0.626, -0.641), n = c(10000, 
            1670, 52, 43, 52, 66, 26, 9, 10, 10, 13, 11, 7, 57, 27, 40, 37, 
            31, 68, 59, 55, 63, 66, 91, 64, 74, 50, 49, 84, 55, 55, 68, 60, 
            76, 45, 64, 44, 29, 33, 25, 17, 25, 21, 20, 18, 32, 13, 20, 13, 
            8, 7, 7, 8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -53L))

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=testage, y=val, weight=n)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = 'Age', limits = c(0,70)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-6,0.8), name = expression(paste("Avg. ",theta))) +
  geom_smooth(size = 1, se=T, fullrange =T, span = 0.3) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0)
```

[image: Average test results by age]

Comment: If you want advice about modeling your data, you should probably ask for help at [stats.se] instead. This doesn't seem like a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow, especially since it doesn't have any sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have added a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `geom_smooth()` geometry in `ggplot2`, you can specify the number of smoothing points as `n = 3`. (You need this to be 3 because the first two are the first and last data point; the third will be the inflection point in the middle.)

You can try smoothing it out further by increasing the `span` argument. It's still not terribly smooth around the inflection point, but possibly the best you're going to get.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot+ 
  geom_smooth(aes(x, y), n = 3, span = 100)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did experiment with different spans, but it did not give me what I was looking for.